# How to debug why a jQuery function is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to get this simple function to work by using this callback but I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I want to invoke a function when the scrolltop is greater than zero. I am new to programming and I can't figure it out.

Is it a formatting issue?

```
function alertme() {
    var $window = $(window);
    var window_top = $window.scrollTop(0);

    if (window_top > 0) {
        alert("alertme");
    };
};
```

Comment: Calling `scrollTop` with an argument sets the scrollTop to that argument. Just call `$window.scrollTop();` to get the value.

Comment: still doesn't work regardless of whether or not I define a value, that was initially why i tried to define the value as 0

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the scrollTop() method to capture the current scroll top and attach an handler to scroll, like this -

```
$(window).scroll(function (e) {
    if($(window).scrollTop()>0) {
        alert("alertme");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! If I may ask, what about my function made it incorrect?

Comment: because window_top should be $window.scrollTop() and not $window.scrollTop(0), since you nullify the scrolltop when you send 0 to the function (and gets the user to the top part of the window).

Comment: @JonathanBaker -- The `.scrollTop()` function has two "modes" (two signatures, sometimes called overloads in other languages, such as C#). If you pass a _value_ into this function (e.g. `scrollTop(0)`) then the function will _set_ the scroll-top position. If you do not pass a value (e.g. `scrollTop()`), then the function will return, or _get_ the scroll-top position. I think this is an awful design decision from the jQuery team in their quest to conquer the land of absolutely newbie/casual programmers, but that's how it is.